# Como renderizar o FullCalendar na segunda pagina do carousel?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Possuo um código para mostrar um carrossel "dinâmico" e dentro do carrossel mostro alguns gráficos FullCalendar.

> O problema : somente os gráficos da primeira página são renderizados, indiferente quantos eu queira que apareçam...

```
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-purple card-outline card-outline-tabs">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $qtd_pages; $i++) : ?>
                                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<?= $i ?>" <?php if ($i == 0) {
                                                                                                            echo 'class="active"';
                                                                                                        } ?>></li>
                            <?php endfor ?>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <?php for ($a = 0; $a < $qtd_pages; $a++) : ?>
                                <div class="carousel-item <?php if (!$a) {
                                                                echo 'active';
                                                            } ?>">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <?php for ($count; $count < $data['qtd_graphs']; $count) : ?>
                                            <?php
                                            if (!$a) {
                                                if ($count == $qtd_por_page) {
                                                    $ind = false;
                                                    break;
                                                } else {
                                                    $ind = true;
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                if ($count == (($a + 1) * $qtd_por_page)) {
                                                    $ind = false;
                                                    break;
                                                } else {
                                                    $ind = true;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3" onclick="carrega_grafico('<?= $data['array_vendedores'][$count][0]['cnpj_estab'] . '?' . $data['mes'] ?>')">
                                                <div class="card">
                                                    <div class="card-header border-0">
                                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                                            <h3 class="card-title" style="margin-bottom:-50px!important;">
                                                                <h3 style="margin-bottom:-60px!important;  font-weight: bold;">
                                                                    <?php
                                                                    if ($data['nome_empresa']) {
                                                                        echo $data['nome_empresa'] . ' - ';
                                                                    }
                                                                    echo $data['array_vendedores'][$count][0]['vendedor'];
                                                                    ?>
                                                                </h3>
                                                            </h3>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="graph_<?= $count ?>" class="calendar"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- FIM GRÁFICO -->
                                            <?php if ($ind) {
                                                $count++;
                                            } ?>
                                        <?php endfor ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endfor ?>
                        </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Possui um codigo ali q faz as divisões das paginas e tem tbm o script js que é feito com php
para cada calendario...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //array com os gráficos
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $data['qtd_graphs']; $i++) : ?>

            $('#graph_<?= $i ?>').fullCalendar({
                weekends: true,
                height: 500,
                firstDay: 1,
                selectable: true,
                defaultDate: '<?= $data['mes'] ?>',
                locale: 'pt-BR',
                header: {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: '',
                    right: ''
                },
                monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua',
                    'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'
                ],
                buttonText: {
                    today: 'hoje',
                    month: 'mês',
                    week: 'semana',
                    day: 'dia'
                },
                events: [<?php for ($e = 0; $e < sizeof($data['array_vendedores'][$i]); $e++) :
                                echo "
            {
                id: '',
                title: '',
                start: '" . $data['array_vendedores'][$i][$e]['data'] . "',
                backgroundColor:'" . $data['array_vendedores'][$i][$e]['cor'] . "',
                rendering: 'background'
            },
            ";
                            endfor; ?>]
            });

        <?php endfor ?>
    });
</script>
```

não acho nada no inspecionar, mas vejo q não escreve os scripts dos ids que vão para a segunda pagina.

desde já agradeço...